# How to add TAX ID when creating a vendor through Rest request in Netsuite?

Tags: rest, netsuite

I want to use this endpoint suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/vendor to create a new vendor.
When I create a vendor through the interface and select a US subsidiary, I can set a simple TAX ID.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETaua.png)
How do I do this when calling this endpoint? I would like to see an actual json example.

I would appreciate another approach if it cannot be done through this endpoint.

I tried these:

```
 "taxRegistration": {
    "items": [
      {
        "id ": "112211",
        "nexusCountry": {
          "id": "US"
        },
        "taxidnum": "112211",
        "refName": "112211"
      }
    ]
  },
```

And also:
  `"taxidnum": "112211",`

But both returned errors in headers.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4cfE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need the SuiteTax feature enabled in order to work with the taxRegistration sublist .

I would start by checking this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do not see the option in Enable Features-> Tax so I believe this feature was not added for this tenant.
However, I can just type the tax id when creating a vendor from the interface. Do you know if there is an API equivalent for that which doesn't require me to activate additional features?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into this. I could not find a way or understand why "taxidnum" cannot be set when posting vendor as a rest record.

My solution was to use a Restlet Script. You will upload the following script into the Netsuite interface and after you deploy it, it will generate an URL that can be calle with the vendor ID and the desired taxidnum.

```html
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Restlet
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define(['N/record'], function(record) {
  function post(context) {
    var vendorId = context.id; // The internal ID of the vendor record
    var taxId = context.taxId; // The tax ID to set for the vendor

    try {
      // Load the vendor record
      var vendorRecord = record.load({
        type: record.Type.VENDOR,
        id: vendorId,
        isDynamic: true
      });

      // Set the tax ID field on the vendor record
      vendorRecord.setValue({
        fieldId: 'taxidnum',
        value: taxId
      });

      // Save the changes to the vendor record
      var vendorRecordId = vendorRecord.save();

      return {
        success: true,
        message: 'Tax ID successfully set for the vendor',
        vendorRecordId: vendorRecordId
      };
    } catch (e) {
      return {
        success: false,
        message: 'An error occurred: ' + e.message
      };
    }
  }

  return {
    post: post
  };
});
```

Request payload example:

```html
{
  "id": "15215",      // Internal ID of the vendor record
  "taxId": "TAX123" // Tax ID to set for the vendor
}
```

Comment: if you don't need any data from the record you may use `record.submitFields`
`record.submitFields({
  type: record.Type.VENDOR,
  id: context.id,
  values: {
    "taxidnum": context.taxId
  }
});`